# How to call setState without getting an infinite loop?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, setstate

I have a StatefulWidget, which needs to retrieve the user's account variable stored in the SharePreferences, to display all of its data in the display and modification forms of the widget.

I am able to read and display these variables in the forms, but my problem comes when I update the account and SharedPreferences variables. With this code, when everything has been updated, my forms are updated as well with the new variables. But it happens that I get an infinite loop, because my success SnackBar pop again and again.

If I don't call _loadAccount() before my SnackBar, the message appears once.

How can I correct this infinite loop ? Which component causes this infinite build ?

```dart
class AccountForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final AccountBloc accountBloc;

  AccountForm({
    Key key,
    @required this.accountBloc
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AccountForm> createState() => _AccountFormState();
}

class _AccountFormState extends State<AccountForm> {

  Account _account;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    _loadAccount();
  }

  void _loadAccount() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map accountMap = json.decode(prefs.getString('account'));
    setState(() {
      _account = Account.fromJson(accountMap);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return _account == null ? new Container() :
    new BlocBuilder<AccountEvent, AccountState>(
      bloc: _accountBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AccountState state) {
        if(state is AccountSuccess) {
          _loadAccount();
          _onWidgetDidBuild(() {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('${state.message}'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
            );
          });
        }

        return new DefaultTabController(
          //...
            body: new TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ListView( // Display form
                  children: [
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                      title: Text('Name'),
                      subtitle: Text(_account.lastName + " " + 
_account.firstName)
                    ), 
                  //...
                ),
                new Form( // Modification form
                  //...
                )
              ]
            )
          )
        );
      }
    );
  }

  void _onWidgetDidBuild(Function callback) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      callback();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: I think that inside BlocBuilder you don't need to call setState, just set the value for your variable. SetState is triggering update, also BlocBuilder is triggering an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I couldn't find a solution. So I changed the entire system of handling events and used the BLOC one instead. With that it worked better, no loop anymore. Thanks anyway